Changing a value of an object of a state variable array
I have an array of objects as a state variable. I am trying to write a function that changes a field in one of the objects.
interface IItem{
 id: string,
 selected: boolean
}

const [array, setArray] = useState<IItem[]>([])

const toggleItem = (id : string) => {
  const item = array.find(i => i.id === id)
  if (item) {
     const copy = {...item, selected: !!item.selected}
     setArray(array.map(i => i.id === id ? copy : i))
  }
} 

The code works, but it looks too complex for this. Is there a way to simplify? (Note, that the order of the items in the array matters).

You could move to useImmer, see this medium article: https://medium.com/@agarwalsahil97/useimmer-a-better-alternative-to-usestate-8208496904c8

"it looks too complex for this" React relies on cheap comparison semantics (i.e. reference equality) to diff the changes in state efficiently, otherwise it would have to do a recursive check on every state object (note this would require a lot of allocations and operations) which would be waaaaay too slow. But this requirement for immutability doesn't mesh well with Javascript semantics. Your only real options are to write code like you wrote, use an immutable data structure library, or not use React.

If you want to simplify state changes, I would recommend checking out the package Immer. With Immer you get a writeable draft of the state that you can mutate. The code might be as long, be if you're working with even more deeply nested object it is very helpful. I also think in you case it helps a lot with readability.
import { useState } from "react";
import { produce } from "immer";

interface IItem {
  id: string;
  selected: boolean;
}

const [array, setArray] = useState<IItem[]>([]);

const toggleItem = (id: string) => {
  setArray(
    produce((draft) => {
      const item = draft.find((el) => el.id === id);
      item.selected = !item.selected;
    }),
  );
};

EDIT
If you don't want to introduce a package for local state, I don't think there's an obvious way to change your code to make it less complex. Here's an alternative at least which I would say is a bit more easy to read.
interface IItem {
  id: string;
  selected: boolean;
}

const [array, setArray] = useState<IItem[]>([]);

const toggleItem = (id: string) => {
  setArray((previous) =>
    previous.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          selected: true,
        };
      }
      return item;
    }),
  );
};



Thanks - that would be indeed a good solution, but I don't want to introduce immer for local state management.

I understand, I added an alternative, but it's not really a big change from your current code. Maybe a slight improvement in readability.

Hide it away in a custom hook:
interface IItem {
  id: string,
  selected: boolean
}

function useSelect<T extends IItem>({ initialItems = [] }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<T[]>(initialItems);

  const toggleItem = (id: string) => {
    const item = items.find(i => i.id === id);
    if (item) {
      const copy = { ...item, selected: !!item.selected }
      setItems(items.map(i => i.id === id ? copy : i))
    }

    return { items, toggleItem };
  }
}

and use it like:
function MyView() {
  const { items, toggleItem } = useSelect({ initialItems: [...] });

  return (
    <>
      {items.map(({ id, selected }) => (
        <div
          key={id}
          onClick={() => toggleItem(id)}>
          {id} {selected ? '(selected)' : ''}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}


You can simplify the function as follows: (same thing, just reduced lines!)
const toggleItem = (id: string) => {
   setArray(array.map(i => (i.id === id) ? {...i, selected: !i.selected} : i));
};


If the id matches, we create a new object with the same properties as
the current item (...i), but we toggle the selected field using
!i.selected.


That mostly just compresses it. The only simplification you've made that wasn't just removing whitespace or locals is that you are now unconditionally iterating the array and setting the state (which triggers a rerender) which may not have acceptable performance characteristics or meet the OPs needs. I'm not saying it's a bad answer, but if you're going to do that at least leave a description of the changes.
